# Why can't I bind my LDAP server in Perl code?

Tags: perl, ldap

I have found some problem with my ldap server, I just can't bind it with my perl script, and here is the script:

```
use strict;
use Net::LDAP;

my $ldap = "";
$ldap = Net::LDAP->new("iis.aulia.net");
my $mesg = "";
$mesg = $ldap->bind("CN=app-audev-adpead,OU=Applications,OU=Special,OU=Users
,OU=FRA,DC=iis,DC=aulia,DC=net", password => "=3\6dsdKDsH30z&B/'Bub00");

die $mesg->error() if $mesg->code();
$mesg = $ldap->unbind;
```

It always shows me :

> 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 at search.pl line 16,  line 522

Do I put a wrong combination after `$mesg = $ldap->bind`? That `"CN=app-audev-adpead"` is my ldap sever user login, and its written in the same format as that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your error

> 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 at search.pl line 16, line 522

The "data 52e" according to [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/LDAP+Error+Code+49) is "invalid credentials".

Possibly to do with you using `\6` in a double quoted string, which will attempt to escape the six, instead of, as I imagine, represent a backslash and a six. So change it to:

```
password => q(=3\6dsdKDsH30z&B/'Bub00)
```

The single quote `q()` will avoid interpolation, and you can change its delimiters to match whatever string you are quoting, for example `q!foo(bar)!`.

You also have a line break in your bind string, which may or may not be significant.

As a side note: Should you really be posting your login information here?

Comment: thanks for your help mate! its working now :). no worry, ive changed some line of my code

Comment: @user2186299 You're welcome. If this answers your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.